# Node noodles getting cut when I change image for image node

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

The attached GIF files below explain what's happening exactly, whenever I open a new image in the Image Node, I lose all connections between output points in the Image Node and their adjacent input points, check first GIF. 
 The weird thing is that it doesn't happen always, only with some files, check the second GIF.
I double checked, all loaded images are Multilayer EXR, with the same amount of passes.
I think there's a simple explanation to what I'm doing wrong, but I can't find it!
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might have to do with the layer names or order, or type, if they are not **exactly** the same blender may not know what to do with them or how to correspond the existing connections to the new layer socket names so it disconnects them. It might also be a bug, and if so it's worth reporting to the bug tracker.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with names, or Blender version, all images are renders of the same file, using the same amount of passes, using Blender 2.78 CR1, the only thing I can point to, is that it didn't happen with images that I rendered as images, while it's happening with images I rendered as animation (using Animation batch render)

Comment: @Georges When you render as Image, how do you save them to disk? Using the save as command or a file output node? Are the file format settings (bit depth, RGBA output, etc.) EXACTLY the same when you do that compared to what you set in the Output section for rendering?

Comment: @aliasguru the settings are the same, as I said in my previous comment, I noticed that when I'm changing in between images that I rendered them using (Render) button and saved them using (F3), the noodles are not cut, but when I change the image to another that I rendered using the (Animation) button, the noodles get cut, I'm sure I haven't change the output settings though.

Comment: I agree with Duarte, this is a case for the bug tracker at https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: There must definitely be something being done different when saving from an *Image Output* Node or directly from an animation. Now whether this is intended behavior, something you unintentionally missed, or an actual bug I cannot tell. If no one else knows maybe report the bug and mention this thread in the description?